# Dimension of induced representation in $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $G=S_3$. It has 3 irreducible representations: $1, sgn$ and $V$; the trivial rep, sign rep and rep $V$ where $dimV=2$

Consider the subgroup $H=S_2$ with irreps $1_H$ and $sgn_H$

> What is the dimension of $Ind_H^G(sgn_H)$?

I know that $|S_3|=6$, $|S_2|=2$ and $|S_3 / S_2|=3$

The induced representation passes from $G$ and $H$ so I suppose dim $\in \{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ but I am unsure

Comment: Have you tried computing the character of $Ind_H^G(sgn_H)$, and evaluating it at the identity?

Comment: I am trying to work through it now. To compute it, do we first need to find $Res(sgn_H)$ which I believe we can get from the character table?

Comment: To compute $Ind_H^G(sgn_H)$, note that you just need $sgn_H$ (which is one-dimensional, and thus is equal to its character), and you have to know something about how $G/H$ looks.

Comment: $S_3/S_2=\{aS_2 | a \in S_3 \}$ so is it a case of computing these cycles? There should be only 3

Comment: You basically have to know when $t^{-1}st\in H$, where $t,s\in G$. You may want to take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_character And if I recall correctly, Serre has a nice presentation of it in his book "Linear Representations of Finite Groups," which you should be able to find with a little Googling.